# JOIN query from scripts in SQL / Impala

Tags: sql, shell, impala

I'd like to create queries for different projects, that all have a base script and then each a customized script.

For illustration purposes, suppose I have these two files with much simplified queries:

```sql
base_dataset.sql

with client_universe as (
select account_id
  , activation_dt
  , suspension_dt
  from clientes 
  where ${product}_flag = 1
)
```

```sql
product_A.sql

, features_1 AS (
select accnt_wid
  , data_1 
from client_universe clnt
left join consumption_A A
  on clnt.account_id = A.account_id
)

, features_2 AS (
select accnt_wid
  , data_2 
from client_universe clnt
left join consumption_B B
  on clnt.account_id = B.account_id
)


select accnt_wid
, activation_dt
, suspension_dt
, data_1 
, data_2
from client_universe clnt
left join features_1 f1
  on clnt.account_wid = f1.account_wid
left join features_2 f2
  on clnt.account_wid = f2.account_wid
)
```

Thus, the compound query is a string concatenation of the two before them which I would like to call something like this.

```shell
$ impala-shell -q -"$(cat base.sql) $(cat product_A.sql)" \
  --var=product="A"
```

and then similarly for `product="B"`.

On one hand, this doesn't work since `cat`-ing the scripts apparently isn't the same as passing it with `-f query-file`.

In addition, this feels rudimentary way of merging the two script files.

Is there a native SQL/Impala way to merge these two?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do? base sql, product_A.sql is not doing anything and just a select. You can use `${product}_flag IN (A,B)` kind of logic - and you can tell me if this will cause issue with data. You can use shell script loop in worst case.

Comment: The reason I separate them is because each product `A` or `B` generates features that shouldn't be in the other.   But there are also features in the query that are common.

Comment: You can use `UNION` clause. I dont see any looping thing in Impala. so your options are shell script loop or may be python script to loop for A and B.